# How to get LLVMTypeRef of a struct?

Tags: rust, llvm, llvm-c++-api

Despite the tag, I'm actually using the [llvm-sys](https://gitlab.com/taricorp/llvm-sys.rs) Rust library, but I believe the API should be the same.

I'm using LLVM to compile a toy programming language I'm creating. In the RTS library for my language, I have a structure `MyStruct`. In the emitted LLVM, this becomes

```
%struct.MyStruct = /* definition of struct */
```

From the documentation, its unclear how I'm meant to get an `LLVMTypeRef` corresponding to this structure:

```
let myStructTypeRef: LLVMTypeRef = /* unsure how to write this code */
let myStructVariable: LLVMValueRef = LLVMBuildAlloca(builder, myStructTypeRef, "myStruct");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `LLVMGetTypeByName` function

https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMCCoreModule.html#ga29066e749e093fba6fedb5efa0962177